# How can I add QVBoxLayout to QGridLayout?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to add a new column to my main window with pyqt5. I guess, I can make it by adding a new QVBoxLayout to main QVGridLayout. Let me explain with drawing.

MainWindow

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I have 3x3 GridLayout. I want to add a new column. In this new column there will be some information texts. So I guess I also need to divide this new column to some rows.

Here the my mainWindow code:

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, cams: Dict[int, str]) -> None:
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.cameras: Dict[int, List[Any]] = OrderedDict()
        index: int
        for index in range(len(cams.keys())):
            self.cameras[index] = [None, None, False]

        index = 0
        for cam_id, link in cams.items():
            self.cameras[index] = [cam_id, link, False]
            index += 1

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(2)

        self.labels: List[QLabel] = []
        self.threads: List[Slot] = []
        for index, value in self.cameras.items():
            cam_id, link, active = value

            slot = Slot(self, index, cam_id, link)
            slot.signal.connect(self.ReadImage)
            self.threads.append(slot)

            label = QLabel()
            label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Ignored)
            label.setScaledContents(True)
            label.setFont(QFont("Times", 30))
            label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255,0,255);"
                            "background-color: rgb(0,0,0);"
                            "qproperty-alignment: AlignCenter;")

            clickable(label).connect(partial(self.showCam, index))
            self.labels.append(label)

            if index == 0:
                layout.addWidget(label, 0, 0)
            elif index == 1:
                layout.addWidget(label, 0, 1)
            elif index == 2:
                layout.addWidget(label, 0, 2)

            #elif index == 3:
                #layout.addWidget(label, 0, 3)

            elif index == 3:
                layout.addWidget(label, 1, 0)
            elif index == 4:
                layout.addWidget(label, 1, 1)
            elif index == 5:
                layout.addWidget(label, 1, 2)

            #elif index == 7:
                #layout.addWidget(label, 1, 3)

            elif index == 6:
                layout.addWidget(label, 2, 0)
            elif index == 7:
                layout.addWidget(label, 2, 1)
            elif index == 8:
                layout.addWidget(label, 2, 2)

            #elif index == 11:
                #layout.addWidget(label, 2, 3)
            #elif index == 12:
                #layout.addWidget(label, 3, 0)
            #elif index == 13:
                #layout.addWidget(label, 3, 1)
            #elif index == 14:
                #layout.addWidget(label, 3, 2)
            #elif index == 15:
                #layout.addWidget(label, 3, 3)

            else:
                raise ValueError("n Camera != rows/cols")

        layout.addWidget(label, 0,3,3,1)
        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        timer.start(1000)
        self.showTime()

        timer_th = QTimer(self)
        timer_th.timeout.connect(self.refresh)
        timer_th.start(60000*60*3)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle('cctv')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))

        self.newWindow = NewWindow(self)
        self.refresh()

    def sizeHint(self) -> QSize:
        return QSize(width, height)

    def resizeEvent(self, event) -> None:
        self.update()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event) -> None:
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.accept()

    def closeEvent(self, event): pass

    def showCam(self, index: Any) -> None:
        self.newWindow.index = index
        if not self.cameras[index][2]:
            text_ = "Camera {}\nNot Active!".format(self.cameras[index][0])
            self.newWindow.label.setText(text_)
        self.newWindow.setWindowTitle('Camera {}'.format(self.cameras[index][0]))
        self.newWindow.show()

    def showTime(self) -> None:
        time = QTime.currentTime()
        textTime = time.toString("hh:mm:ss")

        date = QDate.currentDate()
        textDate = date.toString('ddd,MMMM d')

        text = '{}\n{}'.format(textTime,textDate)

        for index, value in self.cameras.items():
            cam_id, link, active = value
            if not active:
                text_ = "Camera {}\n".format(cam_id) + text
                self.labels[index].setText(text_)

    @pyqtSlot(np.ndarray, int, int, bool)
    def ReadImage(self, im:np.ndarray, index:int, cam_id: int, active:bool) -> None:
        self.cameras[index][2] = active
        cam_id, link, active = self.cameras[index]

        im = QImage(im.data, im.shape[1], im.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()
        self.labels[index].setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(im))

        if index == self.newWindow.index:
            self.newWindow.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(im))

    def refresh(self) -> None:
        for slot in self.threads:
            slot.start()
```

Comment: The [`addLayout`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addLayout-1) method has `rowSpan` and `colSpan` arguments. In this case, you'd use rowSpan=3 and colSpan=1.

Comment: self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()  then  layout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 3, 2, 1)  and then you need to add the widgets (labels .. whatever) to verticalLayout as you did for your labels in the grid, your code misses all the imports and we don't have the dict to fill the label so You need somebody better than me that can run your code in his mind, I need a mre https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to try to help you

Comment: layout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 3, 3,1) sorry for mistake but your widget isn’t populated if the input dict is not there, I guess it would be the same with the QVBox. You’ll have a line for it as long as the accompanying cam is there

Comment: I used the method you provided, thanks. I just edited a few numbers.